# How to prove that $\int_1^\infty \ln (1+\frac{\sin x}{x^p}){\rm d}x$ is divergent for $0<p\leq\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How to prove that $\int_1^\infty \ln (1+\frac{\sin x}{x^p}){\rm d}x$ is divergent for $0<p\leq\frac{1}{2}$?

It is clear that $\ln (1+t)\sim t-\frac{t^2}{2},t\to 0.$ But we could not use this comparison, since the function is not always positive.. or always negative. How to show the divergence then ?

Comment: @haidangel gonna edit each and every post with $d\Xi\mapsto{\rm d}\Xi$?.. (please not mine)

Comment: @metamorphy, okay, I will notice that.

Comment: Break the integral at integral multiples of $\pi$. Add together two consecutive pieces and consider only large $x$. You'll get a convergent integral and one that looks like $\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{2p}}$. Show that the latter diverges for $0<p\le\frac12$.